# Creating File using `resourceGenerators`

Tags: scala, sbt

Given:

```
$cat build.sbt
scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
  val file = (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "demo" / "myapp.properties"
  val contents = "name=%s\nversion=%s".format(name.value,version.value)
  IO.write(file, contents)
  Seq(file)
}.taskValue

$sbt compile
[info] Set current project to sbt_testing (in build file:/home/kmeredith/src/sbt_testing/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/kmeredith/src/sbt_testing/}sbt_testing...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Dec 23, 2016 9:14:50 AM
```

My understanding is that a `myapp.properties` file should been created during the `compile` task.

But, I saw no such file created:

```
$find . -name *.properties
./target/resolution-cache/default/sbt_testing_2.12/0.1-SNAPSHOT/resolved.xml.properties
```

Please explain to me how to generate the `myapp.properties`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong expectation regarding the triggering of the resource generation - running `compile` does not trigger it (compiles existing sources but not generated ones!), but if you execute `test` or `run`, it will be generated:

```
$sbt clean compile
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Dec 23, 2016 5:39:28 PM
[info] Updating {file:/home/tzachz/dev/sbt_testing/}sbt_testing...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 25 Scala sources to /home/tzachz/dev/sbt_testing/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[success] Total time: 24 s, completed Dec 23, 2016 5:39:52 PM

$find . -name "*.properties"
zsh: no matches found: *.properties

$sbt run
// ...

$find . -name "*.properties"
./target/scala-2.11/resource_managed/main/demo/myapp.properties
./target/scala-2.11/classes/demo/myapp.properties
```